# Java 8 Hashmap | Lombok @Data | Method not readable in Collectors.groupingBy | Composite Key

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, lombok, collectors

The following is a bean in use having lombok `@Data` annotation:

```
@Data
public class XxedgeCrtV implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String registryId;
    private String personPartyId; 
    private String source;
    
    private String compositeKey() {
        return registryId + personPartyId + source;
    }
}
```

When I tried to use create hashmap using Java 8 on composite key then it does not read the method:

```
Set<String> duplicates  = xxedgeCrtVList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(XxedgeCrtV::compositeKey, Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1L)
                .map(e -> e.getKey())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Can anyone suggest how to get code read this method?

I am making key of composite keys as I have to search for duplicates in list.

Comment: because it is `private` make it `public` if you want to call it from another class

Comment: *I tried to use create hashmap using Java 8 on composite key*, the code shared doesn't involve a `Map`! By the way, you cannot collect duplicates in a `Set` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is neither an error in the method reference nor the Lombok plugin. The return type of grouping is a `Map`:

```
Map<String, Long> duplicates  = xxedgeCrtVList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(XxedgeCrtV::compositeKey, Collectors.counting()));
```

With this code, I get no compilation error.

I bet this is the IDE issue that should complain about the return type rather than the method reference. There might be also different issue, if so:

- The class `XxedgeCrtV`  if inner shall be `static`.
- The visibility of the `compositeKey` should not be `private` if `XxedgeCrtV` is in a different file.

Comment: are you sure, you understand the question right? or is it just an attempt to address any possible issue that the OP could possibly face? in which case, one would rather, vote to close as unclear or a typo.. isn't it? e.g. one doesn't even know why would that Map now be named as `duplicates`!

Comment: I answer the question "how to get code read this method" (it's not clear itself but one can deduct the compiler complains about the method) with addressing possible issues, where none of them is a typo: `private` vs `public`/`protected`"package-friendly" or static vs. non-static, `Map` vs `Set`. Secondly, the OP states what he does but seems has problem rather with the compilation than the way to get it. I believe as soon as the OP understands the return type of grouping and the compilation issues, he'd be able to achieve his goal (I see no question "how to get duplicates").

Comment: ... continue: Moreover one is definetly able to find duplicates using grouping with `Collectors.counting()` downstream collector which result is further filtered for values larger than 1. Somebody correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: Actually, the `compositeKey` method should be removed. For a composite key, string concatenation is the worst approach. It’s unreliable, as `"ab" + "c"` will clash with `"a" + "bc"`, and it’s expensive. If you don’t want to implement a dedicated key type, you can use `Arrays.asList(registryId, personPartyId, source)`, but here, the class `XxedgeCrtV` *is* already a dedicated composite key type, getting the right `equals` and `hashCode` implementation from Lombok via `@Data` annotation. So just use `Function.identity()` as key function and get a `Map<XxedgeCrtV, Long>`…

Comment: ... or you can use a separator (ex. `-` or `_`) between the Strings in the composite key that never occurs in any of them. The String concatenation itself is a different issue. The answer was not meant to address such issues but the way to make the code compile with a correct return type and help to find a root of the compilation problem, *no* the logics itself (string concatentation, hashcode/equals). I believe these shall be pointed out in a comment below the question and *not* linked to my answer...